# make control for button

Tags: vb.net

I have wanted to ask my problem.
I make 3 buttons, button 1, 2 and 3. so when I click one button automatic button changes color. I'm using code like this

```
For Each ctrl As Control In frm.Controls
   If ctrl = button Then
      ctrl.backcolor = color.red
   End If     
Next
```

but still error. please help me

Comment: You have to mention what the error is exactly!

Answer (score 1):

The right code would be:

```
For Each ctrl As Control In frm.Controls
    If TypeOf ctrl Is Button Then
        DirectCast(ctrl,Button).BackColor = Color.Red
    End If
Next
```

Comment: haha Im a C# guy and I would've never seen that! =P BASIC syntax just doesn't suit my eyes!!

Comment: I believe you still need to _cast_ the `ctrl` to `Button` before you can use any button properties (such as `BackColor`).

Comment: @Oded: You're right about needing to cast the `ctrl` to `Button` (using `DirectCast(ctrl, Button)`) before you can assign button-specific properties. But `BackColor` is an inherited property of `Control`, so this should compile.

Comment: @Code Gray - `Control` has no such property. `WebControl` does.

Comment: @Oded: I was assuming WinForms. `System.Windows.Forms.Control` [definitely](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.backcolor.aspx) has a `BackColor` property. I just tested it in case I was missing something obvious, but the code works fine without casting from the base `Control` type.

Answer (score 0):

Use following code :

```
    For Each ctrl As Control In Controls
        If TypeOf ctrl Is Button Then
            ctrl.BackColor = Color.Red
        End If
    Next
```

What you are doing wrong is compare an instance with a type. What you need to do is compare `Type` of an instance to another `Type`.

Comment: I believe you still need to cast the `ctrl` to `Button` before you can use any button properties (such as `BackColor`).

Comment: No, `BackColor` is a property of class `Control` which `Button` class overrides. Polymorphism, :)

Comment: My point is that [`Control`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.aspx) has no `BackColor` property. `WebControl` does, however.

Comment: Are you confusing `Win Forms` with `WPF`? This guy is using `Win Forms`, not `WPF`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.backcolor.aspx

Comment: The above code change all button. I want to change only the button that I click.

please help me

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the best way. Have a look at the below option.

```
Sub buttons_click(sender as Object, e as event) Handles button1.Click, 
                                                      _ button2.Click, 
                                                      _ button3.Click
    sender.backcolor = color.red
End Sub
```

Sorry if the syntax is a bit off, it's a while since i've done vb.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I believe you still need to cast `sender` to `Button` before you can use any button properties (such as `BackColor`).

Comment: Just tested it and it works. Probably would be safe to cast it though.